# Actionscript 2 - Displaying randomly generated numbers

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm making a game and in it I need to randomly generate two numbers and then display them on the screen. So far I've managed to randomly generate two numbers between 1 and 10 (using a trace to check that this works) but I can't display them on the screen.

I've named the first dynamic text box `VariableA`, and the second `VariableB` and put these on the screen. Also, the code that is displayed below is inside an `if` loop. I worked out how to do this using a tutorial, and what I've done seems to be exactly what they did so I'm really stuck!

My Code so far....

```
VariableA = random (10) +1;

VariableB = random (10) +1;
```

Comment: try this way: `VariableA.text = random (10) +1;`

Comment: Hi, tried this, and used the trace to check it and VariableA comes up as  undefined

Comment: strange... have a look here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000265.html

Comment: Yea this looks like what i've done, but for some odd reason it doesn't work :(

Comment: Where is the code that adds the text to the textfield?  Its hard to help with only the code above.  I want to say the variable you're asking for isn't in the same scope as the request call but without more code to consider I'm only guessing.